# Can you instantiate a nested type of a generic type argument in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

The following code results in a compiler error that I don't see should be necessary. Is there a good workaround?

> error CS0704: A nested type cannot be specified through a type parameter `T'

```
public class Base<T>
{
    public T genericData;
    public Nested data;
    public class Nested
    {
    }

    public static B Create<B>() where B : Base<T>, new() {
        var result = new B();
        result.data = default(B.Nested);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well `data` is of type `Nested` so the code should be `result.data = new Nested()`.  It doesn't matter what type T is.

Comment: Try `Base.Nested`. You know `T` will be derived from `Base`

Comment: Which version of C# are you using? That looks like an odd error message. This code gives me `CS0704 Cannot do member lookup in 'T' because it is a type parameter`

Comment: Base is also generic, I will update the code.

Comment: Using Unity and the .Net 4.6 equivalent (C# 6)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the complete name of `Nested` is actually `Base<T>.Nested`, nothing else. The `Nested`-class thus belongs to the `Base<T>`-class but not to its child-classes. Thus write the following instead:

```
result.data = default(Base<T>.Nested);
```

However the `Base<T>`-qualifier is redundant, as the code already *is* within that class. So you could also just use this:

```
result.data = default(Nested);
```

Apart from this you could also just use `result.Data = null`, as `Base<T>` is a reference-type, which defaults to `null`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the info that I needed. I was worried instantiating `Base<T>.Nested` would be wrong in some way, but if that's ok, then it solves my problem :-)